# Does uniform convergence on any interval of form $[-M,M]$ imply continuïty of limit function?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, uniform-convergence

For the past few days I've been studying Analysis and more specifcally the topic of continuïty. I was making some exercices on this topic and got stuck with a problem which goes as follows. Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of function $f_n : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which converges pointwise to a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We don't know if the converges in uniformly on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, but we do know the convergence is uniform on any interval of the form $[-M,M]$ where $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$. The question then is:
if $f_n$ is continuous in a point $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $n$, can we then conclude that $f$ is continuous in $a$? A follow up question is the same question but with $f_n$ uniformly continuous for every n instead of continuous and the question if f is then uniformly continuous or not.

Now, the first thing I tried was to find a upperbound for $|f(x) - f(a)|$ and I found the following
$$|f(x) - f(a)| = |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - f_n(a)| + |f_n(a) - f(a)|$$
But I could not find a way to make both the first and third term on the right side to be less then $\epsilon /3$, because it seemed like I needed the sequence $(f_n)_n$ to converge uniformly to $f$ on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$. Does anyone have tips in order to solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)).

Comment: " it seemed like I needed the sequence $(f_n)_n$ to converge uniformly to $f$ on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$" no, on $(a-1,a+1)$ (for instance) suffices to choose an appropriate $n$ to make these 2 terms $<\epsilon/3$ for some $n$ (for all $x$ in this interval), and you will even reduce this interval to make the second term also less than $\epsilon/3$ by continuity of that $f_n.$ (All this is about the first question, continuity at $a$, not about uniform continuity on R.)

Comment: You cannot claim uniform continuity by proving it on $[-M,M]$ then letting $M\to\infty$. The issue is that $\delta_M>0$ for each $M$, but maybe $\delta_M\to 0$. For example, $x\mapsto e^x$ is uniformly continuous on every $[-M,M]$, but not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of a locally uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031190/limit-of-a-locally-uniformly-convergent-sequence-of-continuous-functions) it explains more conceptually why uniform convergence on bounded intervals preserves continuity.

Comment: @AnneBauval your first comment helped me out with the first question thank you very much :))

Comment: @AnneBauval Concerning the follow up question (about uniform continuïty), I have a gut feeling this does not hold up, but I can't seem to find a counterexample.

Comment: Look at Andrew's comment above. Find uniformly continuous functions $f_n$ which converge to $\exp$ uniformly on every $[-M,M].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first and third terms you don't need uniform convergence on all of $\mathbb R$. You only need uniform convergence on some interval that contains $a$.

Properly, fix $\def\e{\varepsilon}\e>0$. Since the sequence converges uniformly on $[a-1,a+1]$, there exists $n$ such that $|f(z)-f_n(z)|<\e/3$ for all $z\in[a-1,a+1]$. Since $f_n$ is continuous at $a$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f_n(z)-f_n(a)|<\e/3$ if $z\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$. By shrinking $\delta$ if needed so that it is less than $1$, now the condition $|x-y|<\delta$ guarantees that all three terms are less than $\e/3$.

Comment: yes but i want to find a $\delta$ so that if $|x-a| < \delta$ the upper bound is less then $\epsilon$ but I don't see how i can find such a $\delta$.

Comment: @AnneBauval: fair enough, I have changed that.

Comment: @lukiluk: I have included more detail.

Comment: thank you I made the proof up and checked it with this comment thank you for your help and time @Martin Argerami :))